# Импорт из Excel/CSV в JavaScript

Tags: php, excel, javascript

Нужно сделать импорт из Excel в JS-код, а точнее создать массив из данных этого файла.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, строки при копировании их Экселя разделяются переносами строк, а столбцы - табуляциями. Потому:

```
var text = '_текст_из_Экселя_';
var a = text.replace('\r', '').split('\n');
for(var i = 0, il = a.length; i < il; ++i){
    a[i] = a[i].split('\t');
}
```

Получить текст из Экселя можно, например, при копировании его в текстовое поле.

Comment: Ему по ходу нужно сделать парсинг exсel/csv файла сперва, и результат передать в js! К тому же создавая парсер нужно учитывать версию MS Office и прочие мелочи. Имхо готовый вариант вряд ли кто предоставит без **Donate**)

Comment: Думаю, скоро узнаем. =)

Comment: Как человек, за...шийся парсить 30-метровый прайс, скажу, что все мои проблемы кончились, когда я сказал заказчику "сохраняйте в xml". А потом банально составляем список столбцов, пропускаем строки до `</Styles>` и радостно парсим регуляркой `"<Cell[^>]*>([^<]+)"`

Answer (score 0):

Уже где-то писал.

> Сохрани экселевский файл в текстовый
> "Сохранить как" с разделением по
> табуляции, и обрабатывай его построчно
> + каждую строку explode("t",$string); и получай значения полей.